# Fixing duplicates and invalid data in a string

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that takes data from people who submit me their forms. I have it set up so people can use check boxes to fill out the times of the day they are free. However sometimes people will check "busy all day" and check times like "1:00pm,3:00pm". So that it appears as:

`busy all day,1:00pm,3:00pm`

on the googlesheet. Also sometimes there is duplicates such as:

`free all day, 1:00pm,2:00pm,3:00pm` etc.

Is there a way where I can have my googlesheet validate the data that the people send me? Like checking if a cell has "busy all day" in it and erasing the rest of cells contents besides:

`busy all day`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try formula:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"busy all day|free all day|.*")`

get the result:

```
Data                                    Result
busy all day,1:00pm,3:00pm              busy all day
free all day, 1:00pm,2:00pm,3:00pm      free all day
busy all day                            busy all day
free all day                            free all day
1:00pm,2:00pm                           1:00pm,2:00pm
```

The formula finds and returns "busy all day" or "free all day" or any other text.